# asp.net webforms google login

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, webforms

I have been searching the net for a solution to use a users google account for authentications on a asp.net webform application.

All I want is that the user login to his google account and return to my webform application with display name, google ID and Email form there I will take care of the rest.

I have tried http://dotnetopenauth.net/, Google .Net Api but I never found a working example.

Can anybody point me in the right direction with a example that works. (C# or vb.net)

Comment: Hi Thanks but this for the MVC platform and not webforms :-(

Answer (score 5):

Have you thought about giving [Nemiro.OAuth](http://oauth.nemiro.net/) a try? It's easy to set up, supports asp.net and winforms, and the online documentation is very detailed.

```
protected void RedirectToLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // gets a provider name from the data-provider
  string provider = ((LinkButton)sender).Attributes["data-provider"];
  // build the return address
  string returnUrl = new Uri(Request.Url, "ExternalLoginResult.aspx").AbsoluteUri;
  // redirect user into external site for authorization
  OAuthWeb.RedirectToAuthorization(provider, returnUrl);
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   var result = OAuthWeb.VerifyAuthorization();

   Response.Write(String.Format("Provider: {0}<br />", result.ProviderName));

   if (result.IsSuccessfully)
   {
      // successfully
      var user = result.UserInfo;
      Response.Write(String.Format("User ID:  {0}<br />", user.UserId));
      Response.Write(String.Format("Name:     {0}<br />", user.DisplayName));
      Response.Write(String.Format("Email:    {0}", user.Email));
    }
    else
    {
      // error
      Response.Write(result.ErrorInfo.Message);
    }
 }
```

You can also follow [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/875991/Users-Authorization-through-OAuth-in-NET-Framework#AspNet) for a step-by-step instruction on how to use OAuth with Nemiro.OAuth library.

Comment: Hi Woodykiddy Thanks, but I could not find a working example for use with  Google :-(, so far all the examples has beeen with FB and twitter. Do you have any idea where to find it

Comment: Take a look at this link:  https://github.com/alekseynemiro/nemiro.oauth.dll/blob/master/examples/GoogleDriveWebForms/Global.asax.cs.

Comment: And this help article: http://oauth.nemiro.net/?topic=html/aff36495-124c-a749-20ed-ce08ec915999.htm

Comment: Thaaaaankkks , those links are really great

Comment: @ccr No worries. Hope they helped. Also I'd appreciate it if you can mark my answer.

Comment: Currently, Google Auth is broken for this library: https://github.com/alekseynemiro/nemiro.oauth.dll/issues/26

Comment: @woodykiddy, I need help with Nemiro library. Can you help me? My question is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49465126/using-nemiro-oauth-library-for-google-authentication-in-webforms

Comment: @woodykiddy, thanks and I appreciate your help. I will go through it and let you know.