# Integrate Google login in webforms project

Tags: c#, webforms, google-signin

I want to make a button, in a webforms project, which redirects me to google login. After a user logs I want to get some basic data from his profile, like email and name.

I tried this [Nemiro][1]

[1]: [asp.net webforms google login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39689867/asp-net-webforms-google-login) but I have problems whit it (even whit the default example which return error 401).

I tried this

```
var credentials =
                    GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                            new ClientSecrets { ClientId = "client-Id", ClientSecret = "client-secret" },
                            new[] { "openid", "email" }, "user", CancellationToken.None,null);
```

And it works, but only on localhost. I don't know how to change the redirect uri and because of this I don't think it will work when I will upload it on server.

Also, on youtube I saw they connect to google whit an IAppBuilder, but I can't use it in my project.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to remove your clientid and secret from this site, but also in your application. Following solution works for me:

```
var googleoptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["gid"],
            ClientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["gsecret"]
        };
        googleoptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me");
        googleoptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login");
        googleoptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email");
        googleoptions.Scope.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile");
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleoptions);
```

Don't forget to store your id and secret in appsettings.

To make it work on other locations than localhost, you'll need to add that url to the list in the [Developersconsole of google](https://console.developers.google.com)

Comment: One question. Who is "app" and how can i relate it to a button ?

Comment: "app" is the IAppBuilder added to the startup configuration.
In the folder "app_start" -> "startup.auth.cs"

Comment: I don't have it and i can't modify startup