# Using Nemiro OAuth library for Google authentication in Webforms

Tags: asp.net, webforms, oauth-2.0, google-authentication

I am trying to use Nemiro library to authenticate against Google in a Webforms asp.net project. This library documentation is at [Nemiro GoogleClient Documenation](http://oauth.nemiro.net/?topic=html/aff36495-124c-a749-20ed-ce08ec915999.htm)

I have a simple aspx page called `ExternalLogin.aspx`, whose markup and code-behind are as given below.

**Question**

With code that I have, when `Login using Google` button is clicked, then user does not get directed to Google's authorization  page. What is missing in my code that is causing this?

*Markup*

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="ExternalLogin.aspx.cs" Inherits="ExternalLogin" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="btnGoogle" runat="server" Text="Login using Google" OnClick="btnGoogle_Click" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

*Code-behind*

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using Nemiro;
using Nemiro.OAuth.Clients;
using Nemiro.OAuth;

public partial class ExternalLogin : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void btnGoogle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var result = OAuthWeb.VerifyAuthorization();
        if (result.IsSuccessfully)
        {
            var user = result.UserInfo;
            Response.Write(String.Format("User ID:  {0}<br />", user.UserId));
            Response.Write(String.Format("Name:     {0}<br />", user.DisplayName));
            Response.Write(String.Format("Email:    {0}", user.Email));
        }
    }
}
```

I have also defined the keys for Google OAuth in Application_Start event as below.

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Nemiro.OAuth.OAuthManager.RegisterClient(
              new Nemiro.OAuth.Clients.GoogleClient(
                 "some-value-1",
                 "some-value-2"
               ));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be looking at `OAuthWeb.RedirectToAuthorization` method. Here's the [API doc](http://oauth.nemiro.net/html/3f3ebcbc-1c14-e92c-55ab-40e5a359c5a9.htm) for your reference. So just call this method in your `btnGoogle_Click`, and then verify your authorization in `Page_Load` event handler.

Here's the sample code:

```
protected void btnGoogle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OAuthWeb.RedirectToAuthorization("Google", new Uri(Request.Url, "ExternalLogin.aspx").AbsoluteUri);
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostback)
   {
        var result = OAuthWeb.VerifyAuthorization();
        if (result.IsSuccessfully)
        {
            var user = result.UserInfo;
            Response.Write(String.Format("User ID:  {0}<br />", user.UserId));
            Response.Write(String.Format("Name:     {0}<br />", user.DisplayName));
            Response.Write(String.Format("Email:    {0}", user.Email));
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if you'd like to verify the authorization results on a different page, just change the page name in the URI constructor, and put verification code in the `Page_Load` event of your new page.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I found that instead of the line of code you have have in btnGoogle_Click, the following line also worked: `Response.Redirect(OAuthWeb.GetAuthorizationUrl("Google", "http://localhost:64604/ExternalLoginResult"));`. Probably the line you have also does a Response.Redirect behind-the-scenes.

Comment: Yeah, basically the same stuff, but ideally it's preferred to use Uri class to construct the URL.

Comment: Why is Nemiro so reliable/easy to use, unlike the famous DotNetOpenAuth library which is unreliable and almost impossible to get it to work? I think Nemiro library is the best I have so far come across and also easiest to use.

Comment: I can't agree more. glad we have Nemiro.